# Putting same value in different group in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a column in Tableau - 'Food_Items'. I need to categorise it into 3 groups - 'Breakfast', 'Lunch' and 'Dinner'.

Since few food items can be eaten in more than 1 meal, I need 2 filters in my tableau dasboard - original column 'Food_Items' and Grouped column.

However I want to put same food item in different category. For example, rice is generally eaten in lunch and dinner so I want rice to be included in both 'Lunch' and 'Dinner' group.

Comment: Check out these two pieces of documentation on [sets](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/sortgroup_sets_create.htm) and [groups](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/sortgroup_groups_creating.htm); sets my be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Tableau groups assign each group member to one higher level category (or none). Groups are a very useful feature that can assist in many situations, but is not the right approach if you want some values to be assigned to more than one category. Groups are usually implemented in SQL as CASE statements.

Tableau sets assign possible value from a field to a boolean value, true or false, depending on whether the field value is a member of the set. You could make three sets, one per meal, listing the possible food items that are in each set. So you would have a set of Breakfast Items, a set of Lunch Items etc.

If you want to only display the relevant items for one meal at a time, then you would just need a calculated field to switch between sets.

For example, if your sets were named **Breakfast_Items**, **Lunch_Items** and **Dinner_Items**, then you could create a string valued Parameter called **Current_Meal** that allowed values from the list "Breakfast", "Lunch" and "Dinner", and then create a boolean valued calculated called **Item_In_Current_Meal?** defined as

```
CASE [Current_Meal] 
  WHEN "Breakfast" THEN [Breakfast Items]
  WHEN "Lunch" THEN [Lunch_Items]
  WHEN "Dinner" THEN [Dinner_Items]
END
```

Just referencing a set by name yields a boolean expression indicating whether a data record is associated with (a member of) the set.

Then show the parameter control so that the user can choose the meal type, and put **Item_In_Current_Meal?** on the filter shelf, only choosing True values. So the user can pick a meal and only see data related to that meal.

Or if you wish, replace the **Current_Meal** parameter with a calculated field of the same name that chooses the meal based on the time of day or whatever you like rather than a users choice. Or use a parameter action to choose it via some other user interface action.